# robot_upstart with root permission

Tags: ros, root, permission, robot-upstart

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

My question is: when the .launch file is launched by using robot_upstart set up, does it have root access? I have not tested yet because my package it not ready. Our project uses a headless robot, and there is a package that would use the PRU of the Beaglebone. At the moment, we need to do rosrun from root, in order for this package to work. If the answer is no, could you please suggest some solution to us?

Best regards,

Nhan Nguyen

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188789/robot_upstart-with-root-permission/) by [Nann Nguyen](https://answers.ros.org/users/19924/nann-nguyen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-08-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, here is a detailed explanation
https://github.com/clearpathrobotics/robot_upstart/blob/jade-devel/doc/install.rst

---

Originally posted by [shoemakerlevy9](https://answers.ros.org/users/27706/shoemakerlevy9/) with karma: 545 on 2017-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can make one node of your launch run as root - using `launch-prefix` - while keeping the rest running as user. Here is an example launch file:

```
<launch>
<node pkg="i2cpwm_board" name="i2cpwm_board_node" type="i2cpwm_board" output="screen" launch-prefix="sudo -E ">
</node>
</launch>
```

In this example, we need root access for the I2C device on a Raspberry Pi.

---

Originally posted by [suforeman](https://answers.ros.org/users/28415/suforeman/) with karma: 300 on 2017-03-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1